# Wordpress Facebook plugin: comment too wide

Tags: wordpress, facebook-comments

In my settings, I added as width: 420px, but the box keeps on showing to wide (500px):
example: http://www.amable.be/2012/06/de-onweerstaanbare-schoonheid-van-corsica/

How can I fix?

Comment: whats the plugin name that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the plugin. See [this thread on the Wordpress support site](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-facebook-comment-width-not-adjusting) for instructions on how to fix it, or you can wait for the next update to the plugin to push.